# Swift3 コンパイルエラー

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

```
import Foundation

func stdWeight(hegihtCm height: Double, #bmi: Double) ->  Double{
    return pow(height / 100.0,2) * bmi
}
let height = 180.0
let w1 = stdWeight(hegihtCm: height, bmi: 22.0)
print("身長が\(height)cmの人の標準体重は\(w1)kgです")
```

外部引数と内部引数を同じ名前で公開しようとした際に、
3行目の#bmiのところでExpected parameter name followed by ':'
と、エラーがでてしまっています。
検索をしても解決方法が分からなかったのでご質問させて頂きます。
このコンパイルエラーが分かる方いらっしゃったらご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

ずいぶん古いSwiftの書き方をご存知ですね。現在のSwift(2.0以降)では関数でもメソッドでもすべての(※)パラメータがデフォルトで引数ラベル(外部名)を持つと言うルールに共通化されため、`#`を使った書き方は削除されています。(※Swift2では第1引数のみ別扱い。)

単純に`#`を削除してください。

```
func stdWeight(hegihtCm height: Double, bmi: Double) ->  Double{
    return pow(height / 100.0,2) * bmi
}
```

Comment: 解答でおっしゃられているように現在扱っているのはSwift3です。解答の通り#を消したところ正常に動きました。現在「XcodeではじめるSwiftプログラミング」という本で勉強しているため知識がかなり前のモノになっていました。

Comment: @I_718 さん、Xcodeと言うIDEに固有の話でもないので、xcode7タグは不要(代わりにxcode8タグを付加する必要もない)でしょう。ご自分の質問であればタグ編集もできたかと思うので、できればxcode7タグは削除しておいてください。Swift1から2へは、かなり大きな変更があったのですが、2から3への変更はさらに大きなものがありました。できればSwift3を対象に書かれた書籍(かネット記事でも)を使われないと、Swiftプログラミングそのものより「Swift(1or2)からSwift3への変換方法」の勉強に時間を取られてしまいますよ。

Comment: タグの件に気づかずつけたままでした、ご指摘ありがとうございます。Swiftを勉強する際、変換に時間を取られることが多々有りましたのでご指摘の通り新しい本の購入をしてみたいと思います。質問以外にもアドバイス等ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。